# Как можно при DHCP исключить из выдачи определенное кол-во IP адресов, например 20

Tags: ip, cisco, dhcp, ip-address, cisco-ios

Есть необходимость убрать из выдачи адресов первые несколько штук, есть какая команда или каждый адрес нужно прописывать вручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router(config)#ip dhcp excluded-address ?
  A.B.C.D  Low IP address
Router(config)#ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 ?
  A.B.C.D  High IP address
```

Отсюда:

```
Router(config)#ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.20
```